# Input type range with value on slider

Tags: javascript, html, css, input, web-frontend

I have this input type range property and have done a bit of CSS-Styling to it, but I'm not 100% satisfied with it.

```css
.Sslider {
  -webkit-appearance: none;
  width: 75%;
  height: 15px;
  border-radius: 5px;
  background: #d3d3d3;
  outline: none;
  opacity: 0.7;
  -webkit-transition: .2s;
  transition: opacity .2s;
}

.Sslider:hover {
  opacity: 1;
}

.Sslider::-webkit-slider-thumb {
  -webkit-appearance: none;
  appearance: none;
  width: 25px;
  height: 25px;
  background: #4BD1A0;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.Sslider::-moz-range-thumb {
  width: 25px;
  height: 25px;
  background: #4BD1A0;
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<div class="Sslidecontainer" id="Slider"> <span id="Amount"> Amount</span>
    <input type="range" min="5000" max="10000" step="1000" value="5000" class="Sslider" id="myRange">
 <p>Value: <span id="demo"></span></p>
  </div>
```

I would like to output the input value on my moving slider. Is this in general possible? And if so, how would I approach this?

Thx for help

Comment: Have you tried using an on change or on input handler for the slider and using the value from that change event to update an element to display that value?

Comment: Yeah I did that but I think I have wrongly expressed myself. I would like to have my value shown on my moving slider thingy (the thing you can drag I don't know how its called) and not on some other element.

Answer (score 0):

Here's an example suing a tiny bit of inline JavaScript. If needs become more complicated you could refactor that to an external JS file.

```css
.Sslider {
  -webkit-appearance: none;
  width: 75%;
  height: 15px;
  border-radius: 5px;
  background: #d3d3d3;
  outline: none;
  opacity: 0.7;
  -webkit-transition: .2s;
  transition: opacity .2s;
}

.Sslider:hover {
  opacity: 1;
}

.Sslider::-webkit-slider-thumb {
  -webkit-appearance: none;
  appearance: none;
  width: 25px;
  height: 25px;
  background: #4BD1A0;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.Sslider::-moz-range-thumb {
  width: 25px;
  height: 25px;
  background: #4BD1A0;
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<form oninput="out.value=myRange.value" class="Sslidecontainer" id="Slider">
  <span id="Amount"> Amount</span>
  <input type="range" min="5000" max="10000" step="1000" value="5000" class="Sslider" id="myRange">
 <p>Value: <output name="out" for="myRange" id="demo">5000</output></p>
</form>
```